# Github. How to choose which conflicted binary file to keep?

Tags: git, github

Often when my colleagues or I press the sync button in github for windows it doesnt work due to merge conflicts (We are working on the same branch btw). We are working on a Unity3D game and there are lots of binary files (as in like an image file) which are very easy to accidentally edit so it happens fairly often that two people have edited the same binary file.
When I get this merge conflict I just run 'git add [filepath]' if its one file or' git add -A' if its more than one. This fixes my problem and allows me to commit but I dont understand what is happening there. The nomenclature and usage of git seems very unintuitive to me.
I would expect in a situation where the binary file has been changed by two people that you would get to choose which one to keep. Obviously I would like to keep the version from the person who edited it on purpose rather by accident. How do you do this?

Comment: When you say binary file, do you mean the binary of your source code, or a "binary file" such as a word document or image file etc? These would suggest different approaches. If nothing else, though, may I suggest that a different branching strategy may be appropriate? Or that you may wish to handle binary file versions outside of git

Comment: when I say binary I mean images, dll files, but mainly Unity3D asset files like materials .mat and so on. (they are the ones that we most often get merge conflicts with) Also the thing with using branching is that, in my experience, you are just putting off all these conflicts till when you merge the branches. I'd still like to know how to pick which file to keep when merging branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a merge conflict, you can choose to completely keep either your copy of the file (at the merged commit) or their copy of the file in total without any merging of changes (just one complete version with no changes) using `git co filename.ext --ours` (to keep the version you had before merge/rebase) or `git co filename.ext --theirs` (to keep the version from the other branch before merge-rebase).

This is useful for binary files or products of build processes where it doesn't make sense to try to combine two branches' respective versions.